# Google Cloud Messaging token

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, token

I'd like to know if each time my application runs I need to get the token and pass it to the server, or if it's only necessary once to register the application. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need a token to register the GCM(push notification) to the Google Server. Then this token is passed and used in the server to send subsequent notification. This token should be persisted by the server so that it can be used to make API calls to the Google server. With this approach, your server and the Android device do not need to create a persistent connection and the responsibility of queuing and relaying messages is all handled by Google's servers.

For more information visit the [Registering Client Apps](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#automatic-retry-using-exponential-back-off) and also check this [documentation](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Cloud-Messaging).

Comment: What happens if the token expires?

Comment: GCM server can't respond to your server with some information, but you can call the [onTokenRefresh](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceIDListenerService#public-methods) to make it work again. You can check in the document that I link in the answer on how to do it.